# Check if the parameter passed is 3 digit long and turn every digit into a file in bash script

Tags: bash

I want to pass only one parameter to my bash script and check if the passed argument/parameter is 3 digit long only. After checking this, I want to turn every digit into a file. (eg: bash newscript 123 makes file 1, file2 and file 3)
I have been successful in checking that only one argument is passed by the user, but I haven't been able to figure out the rest of the part since yesterday.

Comment: the argument `477` should produce files `file4` , `file7`, right? (If some digits are equal - it'll produce one file)

Comment: What have you tried so far, post your research efforts

Comment: You are absolutely right @RomanPerekhrest . But that's what I am not able to do at all. Any help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Use the following bash script (`newscript.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash
d=$1    # accessing the first argument
re='^[0-9]{3}$'    # pattern to match 3-digit number
if [[ $d =~ $re ]];
then
    for((i=0;i<${#d};i++)); do touch 'file'"${d:$i:1}"; done
else
    echo "Invalid argument $d"
fi
```

***Usage***:

```
bash newscript.sh 477
```

The above command will create 2 files: `file4` and `file7`

Answer (score 0):

Your question is much more a "How do I validate the input to insure I only create 3 files with names of the form `file_#`?" than how to create the files themselves. None of which is hard, but all need be done to insure you have (1) at least *1-argument* passed to your script; (2) the argument passed is *3-characters* long; (3) each of the 3-characters is a digit; and finally (4) create a file of the form `file_digit` for each digit in your 3-character input.

Putting the pieces together, you can do something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

test -z "$1" && {   ## validate at least on argument given
    printf "error: insufficient input.\nusage: %s <###>\n" "${0##*/}"
    exit 1
}

input="$1"      ## variable holding argument
len=${#input}   ## length of string

(( len == 3)) || {  ## validate 3-chars long
    printf "error: invalid input, input is not 3-characters long.\n"
    exit 1
}

[[ $input =~ [^0-9] ]] && { ## validate input contains only digits
    printf "error: non-digit in input '%s'.\n" "$input"
    exit 1
}

for ((i = 0; i < len; i++)); do     ## create file_# for each number
    touch "file_${input:$i:1}"
done
```

**Erroneous Input Examples (verifications)**

```
$ bash 3digit_input.sh
error: insufficient input.
usage: 3digit_input.sh <###>

$ bash 3digit_input.sh 1a3
error: non-digit in input '1a3'.

$ bash 3digit_input.sh 1a3r
error: invalid input, input is not 3-characters long.
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ bash 3digit_input.sh 123
$ l file_*
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 0 Apr 22 09:50 file_1
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 0 Apr 22 09:50 file_2
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 0 Apr 22 09:50 file_3
```

If that wasn't exactly what you were looking for, or if you have additional questions, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I had to try it with awk:

```
$ echo 123 | awk -F '' '/^[0-9]{3}$/{ "touch " $1 " " $2 " " $3 | getline }'
```